# nesper: how to see audit information

Tags: nesper

When you use the @Audit annotation in a sentence how / where can I find the @audit information in nesper? 
I have configured

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.EngineDefaults.ExecutionConfig.IsPrioritized = true;
    config.EngineDefaults.LoggingConfig.IsEnableExecutionDebug = true;
    config.EngineDefaults.LoggingConfig.IsEnableTimerDebug  = true;
    config.EngineDefaults.LoggingConfig.IsEnableQueryPlan= true;
```

And I use the Log to write the rest of information.

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

But I don't see anything.
I have tried with esper and java, and I see de information.
There is any example?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There is a Log4net config as part of the configs that you can change. The doc also provide some information on the name of the audit logger for log4net.

Comment: Thanks. Please, could you say which configuration is necessary to see the audit information? I have failed.

Comment: <pre> <code><appender name="FileAppender.Audit" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" >
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
      <levelToMatch value="AUDIT" />
    </filter>
    <file value="testrun.audit.log" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" >
      <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss:fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger{1} - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>     
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender.Audit" />
    <level>
    </root> </code></pre>